# Reading pointers twice is giving garbage values

Tags: c++

I want to return an array created in a local function through pointers to the main function. My code is below. The array is returned and I am able to access each element by element once only. The next time it is giving garbage values. What is Wrong?

```
void DoWork(int** ppOut , int& nSize)
{
    int m[5];
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++)
        {
            m[i] = i;
        }

    nSize = 5;
    cout << m[0] << endl;
    cout << m[1] << endl;
    cout << m[2] << endl;
    cout << m[3] << endl;
    cout << m[4] << endl;

    *ppOut = &m[0];

    //delete [] m;
}

void main()
{
    int nSize = -1;
    int i;
    int* f = NULL; 

    DoWork(&f , nSize);

    cout << f[3] << endl;
    cout << f[0] << endl;
    cout << f[2] << endl;
    cout << f[3] << endl;
    cout << f[4] << endl;

    _getch();
}
```

Output is:-- 0 1 2 3 4 from local function. 
        But in main 3 and rest are grabage values

Comment: Plenty of undefined behavior, illegal and/or non-standard C++. Your primary problem is that you are storing a pointer to a temporary. `main()` **always** returns `int`. `_getch()` is certainly non-standard (use `std::cin.ignore()` instead).

Comment: @OP: why not google this... (no, please **don't tell me** that it's hard to search for. I'm not interested in that nonsense.)

Comment: @H2CO3: Because to search on google one needs to understand what to search.

Answer (score 5):

**The Problem:**
The array `m` is a local array which does not exist beyond the lifetime of the function `DoWork()`. When you do so what you end up with is **Undefined Behavior**, which basically means that you can see any observable behavior because the program ceases to be a C++ standard approved program and so it can show(*literally*) any behavior.

**The Solution:**
You will need to extend the lifetime of `m` so that it is still valid even after the function returns. There are number of ways to do this:

- Create an array before the function & pass a pointer to it to the function.
- Create a static array inside the function.
- Use dynamic memory for the array in function (do remember to release it after usage)
- Use global array which can be poulapted inside the function.

Each has own pros and cons and its more of horses for courses.

On a side note, `void main()` is not the standard specified prototype for `main()` it should return an `int`:

```
int main()
```

Comment: But in main function , i am able to get values from m if it is accessed one at a time...i.e f[0] = 0 , f[4]= 4 if used only one if i use it twice it gives garbage value

Comment: @user3144247: It's Undefined to use it _at all_. You're just seeing ghost data that way. Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6445794/560648).

Answer (score 3):

1. The main function in a C++ program should be `int main`
2. Returning a pointer to a local variable exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: Lots of effort here ;P