# Modify vector in function

Tags: c, function, pointers, vector

I have a (probably very basic) problem at modifying a pointer inside of a function. I want to pass a vector to a function. That function creates a similar vector (same size, type etc...) and then I want to assign this new vector to be my old one.

Here's some code to emulate what's happening

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void change(int *vec){
  int i;
  int vec2[10];

  for(i=0;i<10;i++) vec2[i]=i+1;

  vec=vec2;
}

int main(){
  int i,ind[10];

  for(i=0;i<10;i++) ind[i]=i;

  for(i=0;i<10;i++) printf("%d ",ind[i]);
  printf("\n");

  change(ind);

  for(i=0;i<10;i++) printf("%d ",ind[i]);
  printf("\n");

  return 0;
}
```

The output of this program just shows twice the original `ind` vector

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

while I would like

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Take note that this is not my actual code, just a much smaller version to show the problem. I know that in this version I could just modify `vec` inside of the function and call it a day but in my original code I have to do the operations on another vector and at the end modify the original vector.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading pointers twice is giving garbage values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20827415/reading-pointers-twice-is-giving-garbage-values)

Comment: That question ^^ was asked 20 minutes ago. Why absolutely nobody can be bothered to use the search features?

Comment: You don't have vectors but arrays in C. [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) exist in C++!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your `change` function with

```
void change(int *vec){
   int i;
   for(i=0;i<10;i++) vec[i]=i+1;
}
```

and understand that array arguments are [decayed into pointers](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/). See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378555/arrays-decaying-into-pointers).

If you really want to consider arrays as values, wrap them inside some `struct` like

```
struct myarray_st {
  int arr[10];
};
```

then code e.g.

```
struct myarray_st increment(const struct myarray_st*p, int x)
{
   struct myarray_st res;
   for (int i=0; i<10; i++) res.arr[i] = p->arr[i]+x;
   return res;
}
```

or use some pointer as output parameter, e.g.

```
void 
increment_it(struct myarray_st*dst, const struct myarray_st*src, int x)
{
   for (int i=0; i<10; i++) dst->arr[i] = src->arr[i]+x;
}
```

Then code for example

```
struct myarray_st t1, t2;
memset (&t1, 0, sizeof(t1));
memset (&t2, 0, sizeof(t2));
t2 = increment(&t1,7);
increment_it(&t2,&t1,12);
```

Comment: I already know this but I need to operate on 2 vectors, so this is not an option.

Comment: I ended up doing something like this. Defined `vec2` outside of the function and just manually copied `vec2` into `vec` after calling the function.

Answer (score 1):

In your case there is no need to operate on a local array `(vec2[10])`. You can directly operate on the passed array.

Answer (score 0):

Use `memcpy` ([manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memcpy.3.html)) to copy the content of one array to another. You cannot simply assign, because you are using a temporary array inside your function.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot return a statically allocated array like that, Instead, allocated the array dynamically, and pass that pointer. Actually `vec2` is invalid after returning from the function.
SO you can do the following instead..

```
void change(int *vec){
  int i;
  int *vec2=malloc(10*sizeof(int));

  for(i=0;i<10;i++) vec2[i]=i+1;

  vec=vec2;
}
```

**But there is a chance of memory leak in this way. You need to do `free(vec);` outside the function after the need is over.**

In the other hand, You can copy the whole array to the original one using `memcopy`..

```
memcpy(vec,vec2,sizeof(vec2));
```

Comment: memcpy(vec,vec2,10); size 10 wont work. 10 are bytes so only few integers will be copied, not full vector.

Comment: @Digital_Reality, yes.. modified my answer. thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use `vec2` then use code below instead of `vec=vec2;`

```
  memcpy(vec,vec2,sizeof(vec2));
```

Comment: what if `vec` and `vec2` are vectors of structures:   typedef struct {
  int fitness;
  int *ind;
} ga_ind;